# I'm stuck integrating $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx$ using trigonometric substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

When I'm trying to integrate $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx$ using trigonometric substitution, I get stuck. Here's the complete solution so far:

$$
x(\theta)=a\sec{\theta}\\
x'(\theta)=a\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}\\
\theta=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\implies \theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]\\
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx
&=\int \sqrt{[x(\theta)]^2-a^2}x'(\theta)d\theta\\
&=\int \sqrt{a^2\sec^2{\theta}-a^2}a\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}d\theta\\
&=a^2\int \sqrt{\tan^2{\theta}}\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}d\theta\\
&=a^2\int |\tan{\theta}|\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}d\theta
\end{align}
$$

I take it that at this point I end up with two integrals one for when $\tan{\theta}>0$ (on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$) and another one for when $\tan{\theta}<0$ (on $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]$):

$$
\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right): \int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx = a^2\int \tan^2{\theta}\sec{\theta}d\theta\\
\theta\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]: \int \sqrt{x^2-a^2} dx = a^2\int (-\tan{\theta}\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta})d\theta = -a^2\int \tan^2{\theta}\sec{\theta}d\theta
$$

But that doesn't seem to be right because the integral of a function has one unique answer, as far as I know. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let the expression $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ suggest a right triangle.  One side of the triangle  is $x$, one side is $a$ and the last side is $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$.  Then for your trigonometric substituion, let $\theta$ be one of the angles (not the right angle) of that triangle.  After integration, look at your triangle to re-write everything in terms of $x$.

Comment: You should use hyperbolic substitution, it is way more convenient than trigonometric here since $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$. The inverse hyperbolic functions naturally appear in the final solution.

Comment: Integral of a function is unique if it is definite Integral but in your case it's indefinite Integral. Therefore you can not expect unique answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$x=a \cosh{y}\Rightarrow dx=a \sinh{y}\\
\int\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}dx=\int (a \sinh{y})(a \sinh{y})dy\\
=a^{2}\int\frac{\cosh{2y}-1}{2}=\frac{a^{2}}{2}(\frac{\sinh{2y}}{2}-y)+c\\
=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}-\frac{a^{2}}{2}\sinh^{-1}{(\frac{x}{a})}+c$$

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with hyperbolic trig functions, but if you want to use normal ones, it's a bit more fun. Use the substitution $x = a \sec \theta$.

$$
\text{Let } x = a \sec \theta \Longrightarrow \text{d}x = a \sec \theta \tan \theta \text{d} \theta
$$ $$
\Longrightarrow I = \int \sqrt{a^2 \sec^2 \theta - a^2} a \sec \theta \tan \theta \text{d} \theta
$$ $$
= a^2 \int \tan^2 \theta \sec \theta \text{d} \theta
$$

Integration by parts with $u$ = $\tan \theta$ and $\text{d} v$ = $\sec \theta \tan \theta \text{d} \theta$ yields

$$
\frac{I}{a^2} = \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec^3 \theta \text{d} \theta
$$ $$
\Longrightarrow \frac{I}{a^2} = \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int (1 + \tan^2 \theta) \sec \theta \text{d} \theta = \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec \theta \text{d} \theta - \int \tan^2 \theta \sec \theta \text{d} \theta
$$

But we know $\int \tan^2 \theta \sec \theta \text{d} \theta$ from earlier, so
$$
\frac{I}{a^2} = \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec \theta \text{d} \theta - \frac{I}{a^2}
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow \frac{2I}{a^2} = \sec \theta \tan \theta - \ln(\sec \theta + \tan \theta) + C_0, C_0 \in \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow I = \frac{1}{2} a^2 \sec \theta \tan \theta - \frac{1}{2} a^2 \ln(\sec \theta + \tan \theta) + \frac{1}{2} a^2 C_0
$$ A little more work, noting that $x = a \sec \theta$ and $\sqrt{x^2-a^2} = a \tan \theta$, yields
$$
I = \frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2-a^2} - \frac{1}{2} a^2 \ln \left( x + \sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right) + C, C \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Little note, assuming $a \geq 0$, this only works for $x \geq a$. You'll never end up with $\theta \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right]$ in this case. If I'm correct the case where $x \leq -a$ is solved by negating all mentions of $x$ in my above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution needs to be defined as follows:

$$ x=g(\theta)=a\sec{\theta}, \ \ \ \ \theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cup\left[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \\ \implies \ g'(\theta)=a\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}$$

Because:

$$  g'(\theta)=\left(a\sec{\theta}\right)'=\left(\frac{a}{\cos{\theta}}\right)'=a\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos^{2}{\theta}}=a\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}=a\tan{\theta}\sec{\theta}  $$

Defines an inverse function (one to one) that returns positive tangents for the specified interval, since the sine and the cosine have the same sign in said intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sign problem...

Thanks to Marcus, for $\theta\in [0,\frac\pi 2):$
$$
I = \frac{a^2}{2} \sec \theta \tan \theta - \frac{a^2}2 \ln|\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C
$$
On this interval, since $\sec \theta=\frac xa$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}a$ the solution is
$$
I = \frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2-a^2} - \frac{a^2}{2} \ln |x + \sqrt{x^2-a^2}| + C.\tag1
$$
For $\theta\in (\frac\pi 2,\pi]$, OP says negative signs comes giving
$$
I = -\frac{a^2}{2} \sec \theta \tan \theta + \frac{a^2}2 \ln|\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C
$$
On this interval, it is different. We have $\sec \theta=\frac xa$ but $\tan\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}a$. Then, keeping the same $+C$, the solution is
$$
I = -\frac{1}{2} x(-\sqrt{x^2-a^2}) + \frac{a^2}{2} \ln|x-\sqrt{x^2-a^2}| + C$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2-a^2} + \frac{a^2}{2} \ln \left| \frac{x^2-(x^2-a^2)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\right| +C$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}{2} \ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+C\tag2
$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ are same expressions in $x$.